# Unable to execute java programs on ubuntu 14 studio lite

Tags: java, jdk, netbeans

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04 studio lite 32 bit. I have java apps that I created using netbeans 8/open jdk 1.7. They run fine using the netbeans debugger. However when I create the tar, it can't find the JDK. the only thing that shows up on the "open With other " menu is the "Openjdk 7 policy manager".
My other systems that run on Ubuntu 12 have never had this problem. How do I get this working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenJDK not working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/640211/openjdk-not-working)