# No 'Open with' option to open/run jar file with openjdk

Tags: java, gui, openjdk

I have run

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

It says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openjdk-7-jre is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 229 not upgraded.
```

However, In my /usr/share/applications folder, there is no openjdk-7-jre.desktop.
The only file I have found on my computer related to openjdk is OpenJDK Java 7 Policy Tool. What have I done wrong?
I am using it to be able to run .jar files with a doubleclick. I can run them from terminal already, but there is no open with option for java

Comment: If you can't run jar files with a double-click, but can with the Terminal, then that's a problem with your desktop environment or file manager. (You can run `java` from the terminal, right?) Edit: Can you check to see that you have the files `/usr/share/mime-info/openjdk-7-archive.mime` and `/usr/share/application-registry/openjdk-7-archive.applications`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason there is no desktop file for OpenJDK 7.

```
$ apt-file list openjdk-7-jre | grep desktop        
openjdk-7-jre: /usr/share/applications/openjdk-7-policytool.desktop

$ dpkg --get-selections | grep openjdk-7
openjdk-7-jre:amd64             install
```

Install Java with this commands, in order to get the required entry:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default
```

---

Or you could create a `desktop` file for OpenJDK7

Create a new file in `~/.local/share/applications/`

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/openjdk7.desktop
```

and add the lines below:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Open JDK 7 Runtime
Comment=Open JDK 7 Runtime
Exec=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar %f
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=java
MimeType=application/x-java-archive;application/java-archive;application/x-jar;
NoDisplay=true
```

Replace the line

```
Exec=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar %f
```

with the location of your java installation. You can check the installed JREs with:

```
update-alternatives --display java
```

Sample output

```
java - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java - priority 1071
  slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java - priority 1081
  slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java - priority 1083
  slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java - priority 1084
Current 'best' version is '/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java'.
```